# jQuery if (!) vs .not()

Tags: jquery

I have a selector stored in a variable, and I'm checking to see if that selector has a specific class, in order to add another.

Which of the following, is the better method of doing so, and why? Effects on performance etc?

Any other methods are also very welcome.

`if (!selector.hasClass('class-2')) selector.addClass('class-1');`

or

`selector.not('class-2').addClass('class-1');`

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Adam

Comment: write a case in http://jsperf.com/ and check it yourself

Comment: or you can just call addClass(), it will handle the case internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we have a clear winner here, from [this profiling](http://jsperf.com/addclass-vs-conditional-addclass)

```
if (!$x.hasClass('test')) {
  $x.addClass('test');
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for assembling this for me! I'll definitely give jsperf a go in the future!

Answer (score 0):

`.not()` is faster than `.hasClass()`.

**[See not-vs-if-hasclass](http://jsperf.com/not-vs-if-hasclass/2)**

You should be going with second approach when it comes to better performance.

Comment: That test doesn't look right to me.  Surely there's a massive difference between running a jQuery method once with 3 parameters, and running a jQuery method 3 times?

Comment: also, in lots of browsers except new chrome, `not` is rather slow.

Comment: i have tested it on chrome. where result for not was faster when compared to hasClass and attr

Answer (score 0):

`!` is used for any types but `not` is used only for selector. For eg.

```
var something;
if(!something){
//do stuff here
}
```

But it cannot be done with not like this:

```
if(not(something)){
//do stuff here
}
```

So, choosing `not` for selector while selecting the selector would be best and choosing `!` would be best when you are arguing.

---

If you really interested then you can check [this](http://jsperf.com/) as @Arun P Johny said.